# Smooth scrolling to an anchor after clicking an anchor link on a different site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After searching google for a while I found several ways to animate the way to an anchor, when both (anchor-link and anchor) are on the same page:

```
$('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(href).offset().top},'slow');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

But i coulnt solve the problem, when the anchor link is clicked on a different site.

**EXAMPLE:**

**index.php** there is an anchor link like:

```
<a href="team.php#marketing">marketing team</a>
```

**team.php** there is the anchor:

```
<h2 id="marketing">our marketing team</h2>
```

This works as suggested, but without animation...

I tried this code in the **team.php** but it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(location.hash).offset().‌​top}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript to scroll down, just use a query string and let JavaScript act on that:

`<a href="team.php?target=marketing">marketing team</a>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.search === "?target=marketing") {
        var target = $("#marketing");
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```